# R: iterate through list of start and end dates and insert into an API request

Tags: json, r, api, loops

To save time I would like to iterate through a vector of month start and month end dates and make an API request each time and store the output from each request.

Say we start with a dataframe called dateTable holding the first and last day of the month for the date range:

```
firstDOM    lastDOM
2016-05-01  2016-05-31
2016-06-01  2016-06-30
2016-07-01  2016-07-31
2016-08-01  2016-08-31
2016-09-01  2016-09-30
2016-10-01  2016-10-31
2016-11-01  2016-11-30
2016-12-01  2016-12-31
2017-01-01  2017-01-31
2017-02-01  2017-02-28
2017-03-01  2017-03-31
2017-04-01  2017-04-30
2017-05-01  2017-05-31
2017-06-01  2017-06-30
2017-07-01  2017-07-31
2017-08-01  2017-08-31
```

I would like to iterate through each row and paste the startDate and endDate into the following rest API request however I keep getting the following error when running this piece of code and I am not sure what's causing it:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dateTable)) {
startDate <- dateTable$firstDOM
endDate <- dateTable$lastDOM

#Obtian the Volume of Mentions by Day using declared specs from above
qryMen <- GET(paste("https://newapi.brandwatch.com/projects/", projId, dataSpec
                , "?queryId=", queryId, "&startDate=", startDate, "&endDate=", endDate
                , '&pageSize=', pageSize, "&access_token=", accessToken$access_token, sep = ""))
}

#Error
Error: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are passing the entire vector in your `for` loop with each iteration and not indexing by the loop variable, `i`:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dateTable)) {
   startDate <- dateTable$firstDOM[[i]]
   endDate <- dateTable$lastDOM[[i]]
   ...
}
```

Nonetheless, consider `Map` (or the equivalent `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`) to iterate elementwise through the two columns. With this approach you can save a large list of objects (whatever your query returns) with number of elements equal to the rows of *dataTable*. You can then use this list for further operations.

```
api_fct <- function(startDate, endDate) {

  qryMen <- GET(paste0("https://newapi.brandwatch.com/projects/", projId, dataSpec
                , "?queryId=", queryId, "&startDate=", startDate, "&endDate=", endDate
                , '&pageSize=', pageSize, "&access_token=", accessToken$access_token))

}

api_list <- Map(api_fct, dateTable$firstDOM, dateTable$lastDOM)

# api_list <- mapply(api_fct, dateTable$firstDOM, dateTable$lastDOM, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue I was having! Your solution worked and I will spend time on the apply family

Answer (score 0):

Couple things, your for loop isn't actually doing anything. You say `for i in ...` but you never reference `i` again. And, there's no reason to put the startDate and endDate in the loop. Also, it'd help if you post some sample data so that we can attempt to recreate what you are doing.

Anyway, The error is telling you what is wrong: you can't pass a vector of URLs to GET. Take everything you passed to GET() and just paste it into the console. You'll get back n URLs, n being the number of rows in your dateTable.

I'm assuming your R objects that you pass to GET (other than startDate and endDate) don't change? If that's the case, and you want to use a loop, you can preallocate a vector of the same length as the data you expect to return, then loop through your startDate and endDate, passing them into GET() and slotting them into your `qryMen` object.

```
startDate <- dateTable$firstDOM
endDate <- dateTable$lastDOM
qryMen <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(dataTable)
for (i in 1:nrow(dateTable)) {
  qryMen[i] <- GET(paste("https://newapi.brandwatch.com/projects/", projId,
                dataSpec, "?queryId=", queryId, 
                "&startDate=", startDate[i], 
                "&endDate=", endDate[i],
                "&pageSize=", pageSize,
                "&access_token=", accessToken$access_token, sep = ""))
}
```

Comment: Use R's *apply* family to create list of objects without needing to initialize it.

Comment: That's what I would do as well, but Apply can be intimidating to new R users. (I guess I'm assuming the poster is new.)